ODE with non-negative initial value has a non-negative solution?
Consider the coupled system of ordinary differential equations given by
$$ \dot{x}_i (t) = g_i(t) \cdot f_i( x_{i+1}(t) ), \ i = 1, \ldots, n. (x_{n+1} = x_1)$$
$$ x_i(t_0) = x_{0,i}>0.$$
If each $g_i, \,f_i$ are non-decreasing and $g_i (t), \, f_i(x)>0$ if $t, \,x>0$, is true that the condition $x_{0,i}>0$ implies that the components of solution $x_i$ are non negative? In general, is this always true? What non-negative initial data generates a non-negative solution?

Is it $g_i(x)$ or $g_i(t)$?

$g_i(t)$ I fixed it.

So for each i you have x_i‘(t)>0, t>=0, and x_i(0)>0. So x_i is an increasing function and therefore x_i(t)>0. the relation between the x_i doesn‘t even matter.
